# Select list with decreasing matched result

Tags: sql-server-2008

Need to know the best way to write a query to show the search result in decreasing best matched order.

For ex: search parameters are Last Name, First Name, SSN, DOB, Address
Now, the first row will be that for which all the parameters got matched.
Next row will be that for which the lesser number of parameters got matched
and so on.

[image]

Please suggest!

Thanks
Anant

Comment: You can't do this directly. You need to define proper table structure for this requirement. Please put more information about the requirement.

Comment: Below solution worked fine in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a simple case statement + addition would be the best.  Easy to scale/maintain.  not much overhead, uses exact matching.

```
SELECT lastName, FirstName, SSN, DOB, Address, 
  CASE when lastName = @lastName then 1 else 0 end + 
  CASE when FirstName = @FirstName then 1 else 0 end + 
  CASE when DOB = @DOB then 1 else 0 end +
  CASE when Address1 = @Address1 then 1 else 0 end + 
  CASE when SSN = @SSN_No then 1 else 0 end as Matched 
FROM Table
ORDER BY matched Desc
```